# How to check already existing latitude and longitude in Mongo DB before adding?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

I defined a schema like this to store locations. Now I want to add a location by checking lat and long.

```
export interface Location {
  type: string;
  coordinates: [number];
}

const pointSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true,
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true,
  },
});

export interface Address extends Document {
  streetNo: string;
  addressStr: string;
  country: string;
  postalCode: string;
  location: Location;
}

const AddressSchema = new Schema<Address>(
  {
    streetNo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    addressStr: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    postalCode: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    location: pointSchema,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

//creating 2dsphere
AddressSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });

export const AddressModel = model<Address>('address', AddressSchema);
```

Now the problem is, I already have a location with these pair of coordinates[41.3326643802915, 19.8263257802915] now I need to add  location with these coordinates [41.3326643802986, 19.8263257802456]. So I'm checking these pair is already exists in schema, instead of getting empty result am getting location which has these [41.3326643802915, 19.8263257802915].

Code for checking Existing coordinate:

```
AddressModel.findOne({
        coordinates: { $all: [41.3326643802986, 19.8263257802456]},
      }).lean();
```

Comment: Hello! Please provide the code that is not working for you. Why is it not working? What did you expect? What else have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might also be worth a read :)

Comment: Hey Elias, thanks for checking out my question. Now I provided enough details I guess. please have a look. Thanks